# Access files stored in Ubuntu on windows XP machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, bootable-media

I have saved a file using Ubuntu from a bootable flash drive inside 'Documents' now I want to access this file suing WindowsXP, where can I find it? where does Ubuntu store the files on WinXP

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't store files in Windows XP unless you explicitly save the file to the Windows partition while you're in your live USB session. But if I understand you correctly, you just saved it to Ubuntu's Documents folder. If so, that file is now gone.

Comment: Ubuntu can save files in any version of Windows. If the file was put in "Documents", then that is where it would be. I do not understand what there can be a question about.

Comment: I took it to mean OP was in a live USB session on a PC that has Windows XP installed on it and he simply saved the file to the Documents folder in Ubuntu and now is wondering why he can't find it in Windows when he boots into it instead of the live session.

Comment: Ubuntu "documents" is not the same place as Windows XP "documents" despite the same name. Please clarify how are you accessing Ubuntu? If you are accessing Ubuntu using some sort of Live CD / Live USB, then that files in Ubuntu "documents" maybe lost.

Comment: @Darius I used a bootable flash drive, so the document files aren't saved at all?

Comment: @EH It.. depends. If it is a standard LiveUSB (without persistent storage) then most likely it is lost. If it was made with Persistent Storage - then it should be in the USB somewhere. If you still have the USB, boot to it again, and see if the document files are still in there (if yes - it was built using persistent storage, if not, sorry).